# iOS 9 delete data in HealthKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit, hkhealthstore

While I am trying to delete some records I previously saved in HealthKit, I got an error if I use `-deleteObjectsOfType:predicate:withCompletion:`. The error says:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.healthd.server" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.healthd.server}
```

But if I first query the records using the same type and predicate, and then delete the returned samples with `-deleteObjects:withCompletion:`. It works.

Here's the type and predicate if it helps:

```
HKCategoryType *type = [HKCategoryType categoryTypeForIdentifier:HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMenstrualFlow];
NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSource:[HKSource defaultSource]];
```

Anyone had the same issue? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a bug you should file with Apple (https://bugreport.apple.com).  What predicate are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with `deleteObjectsOfType:predicate:withCompletion:` when using some predicates (including the one you've specified).  The workaround you describe is appropriate.  And as I mentioned in the comments, you should file a bug with Apple.

However, note that the specifying the predicate `[HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSource:[HKSource defaultSource]]` when deleting objects is unnecessary.  Your app can only delete its own samples, so it is redundant to provide a predicate that matches samples from the default source.